# Actualizar datos TABLA (nombres y fecha_registro)

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysqli_query($conection, "SELECT date_format(fecha_registro, '%d-%m-%Y %h:%m %p') AS fec_reg, a.nombres WHERE id_usuario = '".$_POST["id_usuario"]."' ");
```

Utilizo esta consulta para mostrarla en mi form
pero al actualizar

```
$sql_update = mysqli_query($conection,"UPDATE usuarios SET nombres = '$nombres', fecha_registro = '$fec_reg' WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' ");
```

Me imagino debo convertir la fecha a yyyy-M-D para subirlo a la base de datos pero no se como se hace ¿pueden ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar `STR_TO_DATE('date', '%Y-%m-%d')` para actualizar en tu base de datos, sin embargo me parece que no hay problema, otra opcion seria con php algo asi

```
$hoy = date("yyyy-mm-dd",strtotime($dateFromDB));
```

Answer (score 0):

Si tu fecha esta en $fec_reg, debes convertirla al tipo time, y luego le das el formato que quieras con la función date().

Si el campo en la base de datos es de tipo date:

```
$fec_reg = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($fec_reg));
```

Si el campo en la base de datos es de tipo datetime o timestamp:

```
$fec_reg = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($fec_reg));
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Necesitas guardar la hora, minutos y segundos, o solo quieres YYYY-mm-dd como dices en tu pregunta?

La forma más fácil es:

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime($fec_reg));
```

y usas esa variable para hacer tu actualización